# CSS create text with inline image rollover

Tags: css, background-image

I'm currently using this current HTML markup with Javascript to create text links with a inline image that "rolls over" on the text hover.

```
<div><a id="link" href="page.html"
        onmouseover="rollover(this.id,'over');"
        onmouseout="rollover(this.id,'out')"
     >Link</a><img id="linkButton" src="image.gif" /></div>
```

It's important that the image is inline so I can easily create new text links with varying lengths of text.

I want to try and get this done without Javascript, and using a single image containing the over and out states of the rollover, so probably using the background position trick.

Comment: If you know the `background-position` 'trick', what problems are you having implementing this? Where are you stuck?

Comment: The issue is it isn't just an image link there is text of varying lengths before it so I can't just affect the background image of the A tag.

Comment: So why did you not show an example of that markup? Please, give us an idea of what you're working with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `background-image` (or just `background`) in CSS. Here is an example http://www.webvamp.co.uk/blog/coding/css-image-rollovers/

The key is using pseudo classes on the link element. Eg:

```
a:hover
a:active
a:visited
```

You can also use `inline-block` so that the `a` isn't completely a block element. You may want to set a width and a height to it. Keep in mind `display:inline-block` doesn't work that great in IE7, if you still need to support that.

Here's some additional tips on using [CSS Sprites](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/)

Comment: But where would I be applying the background style when the width of the A link varies depending on the amount text used.

Comment: You would apply it to the `a`. What issue is it you think is caused by the variable width? The background repeating? If so, you can just set `background-repeat:no-repeat;`

Comment: The problem is the image is to the right of the text, I can't set a constant left/right position for the background as sometimes it needs to be further to the right for longer text.

Comment: You can put padding on the right side of the link. Make the padding equal to the amount of space you want the image to have. If you're doing it now in JS, you should be able to do it without issue in CSS.

Comment: That doesn't make sense, I can't anchor the image to the right when using background-position, it has to be a pixel value or anchored right. So if I want to shift the image up to create the rollover I can't have it anchored to the right it must also have an explicit left/right value which I can't do due the varying lengths of text.

Comment: I found a solution by switching between 'bottom right' and 'top right' for background position.